# How to compare cell value to ComboBox entry?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I created a `UserForm` with some textboxes and comboboxes. The data typed in textboxes are supposed to be inserted in a cell in the sheet. The determination of which cell is based on the value in ComboBox4.

The code gives me:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

at

```
If Cells(C + 1, 1) Like ComboBox4 Then
```

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox3.List = [ADMIN!e2:E1000].Value
    ComboBox4.List = [PRODUCTION!O6:O1000].Value
End Sub

Private Sub ACCEPTBUTTON_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("PRODUCTION").Activate

Dim C As Long
For C = 1000 To 1 Step -1
If Cells(C + 1, 1) Like ComboBox4 Then

Cells(C + 1, 1).EntireRow.Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If
Next C

Range("AC" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = TextBox1.Value
Range("AD" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = TextBox2.Value
Range("AE" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = TextBox3.Value
Range("AF" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = TextBox4.Value
Range("AG" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = TextBox5.Value
Range("AH" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = TextBox6.Value
Range("AI" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = TextBox7.Value
Range("AJ" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = TextBox8.Value

ActiveCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = 16

Unload Me
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error? What does it stop on when you click Debug?

Comment: @braX the error is given at **If Cells(C + 1, 1) Like ComboBox4 Then**, well it perfectly does select the correct row after i run it, yet it gets the debugger and doesnt input the data from the textboxes.

Comment: Maybe that should be `If Cells(C + 1, 1).Value Like ComboBox4.Value Then`   ?

Comment: @CLR this give me the same error.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `Like`? You probably want to at least try `If Cells(C + 1, 1).Value = ComboBox4.Value Then`

Comment: Why not use `If Instr(Cells(C + 1, 1).Value, ComboBox4.Value) > 0 Then`  ?  Also, if you add a line `Debug.Print ComboBox4.Value` , what are you getting ?

Comment: @Brax i do not have a specific reason but also if i use the code 'If Cells(C + 1, 1).Value = ComboBox4.Value Then' it gives me the same error.

Comment: What is the value of `Cells(C + 1, 1).Value` when you get the error?

Comment: @braX the value is "BIN 1 (2023) - 01/01/22 - KOGI - 19 - BATCH - 2"

Comment: Also, the value of `ComboBox4.Value`?

Comment: @braX if i hoover over the 'Cells(C + 1, 1).Value' when in debugging is shows **Cells(C + 1, 1) = Error 2015** if i hoover over ComboBox4 it shows **BIN 1 (2023) - 01/01/22 - KOGI - 19 - BATCH - 2**

Comment: Use `IsError` on the cell to check that cell value before doing the comparison then. (or figure out why that cell has an error in the first place, and fix it somewhere else)

Comment: @braX, i do not understand....

Comment: This may not be your exact problem, but it will help avoid future problems if you learn to [fully qualify your references](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references)

Comment: As @NewbieNils stated, the cell `Cells(C + 1, 1)` is reporting an error when you try to get its value. You must figure out why. In your code you can test the cell to see if it has valid data first by `If IsError(Cells(C + 1, 1)) Then ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some commented code that should work for you.  I did find it strange that you populate the values in ComboBox4 from column O, but then search column A for matches, is that intentional? (In the provided code, it searches for matches from the same list as populated the combobox which will guarantee a match is found).

Also, instead of a 1000 long loop to find the matches, this uses a Range.Find loop to increase speed and efficiency.

```
'Declare userform variables that any of this userform's Subs can reference
Private wb As Workbook
Private wsAdm As Worksheet
Private wsPrd As Worksheet
Private rAdmList As Range
Private rPrdList As Range

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    'Populate userform variables
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsAdm = wb.Worksheets("ADMIN")
    Set wsPrd = wb.Worksheets("PRODUCTION")
    Set rAdmList = wsAdm.Range("E2", wsAdm.Cells(wsAdm.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))  'Dynamically size list
    Set rPrdList = wsPrd.Range("O6", wsPrd.Cells(wsPrd.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp))  'Dynamically size list
    
    Me.ComboBox3.List = rAdmList.Value
    Me.ComboBox4.List = rPrdList.Value
    
End Sub

Private Sub ACCEPTBUTTON_Click()
    
    'Check if anything is selected from ComboBox4
    If Me.ComboBox4.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Me.ComboBox4.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Must select a Production item"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'An item from the production list in combobox4 has been confirmed to be selected
    'Search the corresonding ComboBox4 list range to find the corresponding row
    '(In your original code, you are searching column A instead of the column that populated the combobox which is column O, is there a reason for that?)
    Dim rFound As Range, sFirst As String
    Set rFound = rPrdList.Find(Me.ComboBox4.Text, rPrdList(rPrdList.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address 'Record first address of found item
        Do
            'Matching row found, unhide and populate cells with textbox values
            'Note that there is currently no check or validation that the textboxes are populated
            rFound.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            wsPrd.Cells(rFound.Row, "AC").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
            wsPrd.Cells(rFound.Row, "AD").Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
            wsPrd.Cells(rFound.Row, "AE").Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
            wsPrd.Cells(rFound.Row, "AF").Value = Me.TextBox4.Text
            wsPrd.Cells(rFound.Row, "AG").Value = Me.TextBox5.Text
            wsPrd.Cells(rFound.Row, "AH").Value = Me.TextBox6.Text
            wsPrd.Cells(rFound.Row, "AI").Value = Me.TextBox7.Text
            wsPrd.Cells(rFound.Row, "AJ").Value = Me.TextBox8.Text
            
            'Search for next cell that matches
            Set rFound = rPrdList.FindNext(rFound)
        Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst 'Loop until back at first address
    Else
        'If the item wasn't found, it's because the user manually typed in something in the combobox, or other error occurred
        Me.ComboBox4.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Invalid value entered for Production item"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Unload Me
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, this code is working perfectly!